# Click the device back button closes the app instead of going back to previous page in android 9

Tags: ionic-framework

In ionic framework,clicking back button to close app instead of going back to previous page.It is only happen in android 9.Work fine in other android version.

I already wrote these code in app.component.ts

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.router.isActive('/home', true) && this.router.url === '/home') {
        navigator['app'].exitApp();
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution : in homepage.ts May be work

ionViewDidEnter(){

this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{

navigator['app'].exitApp(); });

}

ionViewWillLeave(){

this.subscription.unsubscribe();

}